# Add aria-label on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add aria-label to a button? From:

```
<button type="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
```

to:

```
<button role="button" aria-label="slide-dot" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
```

I've tried to use `document.getElementById('owl-dot').setAttribute('aria-label', 'slide-dot');` but it's not working.

Comment: Your button does not have an id of `owl-dot` so `getElementById` doesn't find it.  Either get by class or give it the id.  Once it has an id, the `setAttribute` works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fb3pxdoq/

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is correct, please make sure it runs after DOM is ready.

```
document.getElementById('owl-dot').setAttribute('aria-label', 'slide-dot')
```

In fact, you do not need to add `aria-label` for current button DOM since the inside content could be read out instead.

The `aria-label` should be added to button DOM only when:

1. The DOMs inside are have too many levels, then the count string might not be read out.
2. The `aria-label` is different from inside content string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it provides good documentation as to when or how to use.

https://www.aditus.io/aria/aria-label/

Answer (score 0):

your code is not working because the owl-dot is a class. if want to use your code add the owl-dot id to your button but you can also use the class to set the aria-label value.

```
$(".owl-dot").attr('aria-label',"slide-dot");
```

Comment: try   `document.getElementById('slider_1706').getElementsByClassName('owl-dot').setAttribute('aria-label', 'dot')` but not working

Comment: @SarahC your post doesn't mention anything about "#slider_1706" - does *that* have a missing ID as well?

Comment: if you want to use the slider_1706 use this code

$("#slider_1706").attr('aria-label',"slide-dot");